# Visa for Italy, leaving on flight to Lisbon 9/4/18 scheduled arrival in Rome 9/5/18

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I am  a Catholic priest with appointment as ass't pastor at American Church in Rome. Visa papers in order I hope with letter from Vatican Secretary of State and American pastor in Rome with whom I'll be working. Stay is about 11 months. Please help me. Thank you. Bernard J. Campbell

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Are you saying that you have all you need to apply for the visa but haven't done so? If so, you would apply for the visa for religious reasons at the [Consulate in New York](https://consnewyork.esteri.it/consolato_newyork/en/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/) which operates only by on-line appointments booked through this link http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en

Comment: @Giorgio, religious or work? I presume the OP will be paid for his work in Italy.

Comment: @o.m. You're right; the religious is a C/90 days, he would need a D

Answer (score 4):

- From the tag [us-visa-waiver-program](/questions/tagged/us-visa-waiver-program) I guess you are an US citizen. (Using the tag that way is wrong, by the way, the program is for visitors *to* the US.)
- As an US citizen, you would need a long-stay visa to visit Italy for more than 90 days out of every 180 days. The Vatican is *de facto* treated as part of the Schengen territory.
- You might go to the Vatican visa-free and then stay on Vatican territory after your free days run out, but documenting that would be difficult. There could be problems on departure if your claims that you did not overstay on Italian territory are not believed.
- For details on long-stay visa, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.